# Extra horizontal spacing of zero width box

Tags: spacing, boxes, horizontal-spacing

I would like to add a pair of gray quotation marks around the text without affecting the surrounded text. For this I tried to use `\makebox` with zero width. However, I was still getting:

[image]

To my understanding, as the box has zero width, I should get vertically aligned text. I suspect that this may have something to do with the `\leavevmode` inside `\makebox`, but I don't know how to properly cancel this extra horizontal spacing.

Below is a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment { excerpt } { }
  {
    \raisebox{-.5ex}{\makebox[0pt]{\Large\textcolor{gray!55}{``}}}
  }
  {
    \unskip \nobreakspace
    \raisebox{-.5ex}{\makebox[0pt]{\Large\textcolor{gray!55}{''}}}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{excerpt}
  \blindtext
\end{excerpt}

\begin{excerpt}
  Text for testing.
\end{excerpt}

Text for testing.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want `\makebox[0pt]{...}`, but either `\makebox[0pt][r]{...}` or `\makebox[0pt][l]{...}`, besides better controlling spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{excerpt}{}
  {%
    \raisebox{-.5ex}{\makebox[0pt][r]{\Large\textcolor{gray!55}{``}}}\ignorespaces
  }
  {%
    \unskip
    \raisebox{-.5ex}{\makebox[0pt][l]{\Large\textcolor{gray!55}{''}}}\ignorespacesafterend
  }

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{excerpt}
  \blindtext
\end{excerpt}

\begin{excerpt}
  Text for testing.
\end{excerpt}

Text for testing.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use `\llap` for the start.  And use `\ignorespaces`.  For the end you don't need any width adjustment.  I commented out the `\nobreakspace` there.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment { excerpt } { }
  {
    \raisebox{-.5ex}{\llap{\Large\textcolor{gray!55}{``}}}
    \ignorespaces
  }
  {
    \unskip 
    %\nobreakspace
    \raisebox{-.5ex}{\Large\textcolor{gray!55}{''}}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{excerpt}
  \blindtext
\end{excerpt}

\begin{excerpt}
  Text for testing.
\end{excerpt}

Text for testing.

\end{document}
```

[image: output with quotes]